# Arithmetic operation in SQL SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, arithmetic-expressions

here is the sql query that i've tried.

```
function getall() { 
   $connection = new Connection; 
   $connection->open(); 
   $query = "SELECT position.id,position.name_position,position.g_position,position.cs,position.totalbefore,
            COUNT(position2.staff_id) AS cnt_staff,
            totalbefore-cnt_staff AS totalafter
            FROM position
            INNER JOIN position2 ON position.id = position2.id_position2
            WHERE position.status_data= '1'
            GROUP BY position2.id_position2";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    return $result; 
}
```

This code return syntax error. Idk where to put the Arithmetic operation (totalbefore-cnt_staff AS totalafter) in the statement.can anyone help me pls

Comment: Check you column name like this "totalbefore-cnt_staff". It may be totalbefore_cnt_staff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
position.totalbefore - COUNT(position2.staff_id) AS totalafter
```

You need to calculate the value again

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a group by clause in the query, you must use an aggregate function with your arithmetic expression such as

```
sum(totalbefore-cnt_staff) as totalafter
```

and the same for the totalbefore column.

anyways, try to put the query in any query editor such as (SQL query editor) and the error messages will be more clear for you.